# Print a page: apply css on every page for a breaking element

Tags: html, css, printing

I try to print an html page. It contains a bordered div with a text which doesn't fit on a one page. The code is following:

```
.border {
    border: black solid 1px;
}

<div class="border">... long text ...</div>
```

The result something like this:

[image]

How can I add bottom and top borders in places where the element is moved to another page?

In case you need [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31e2y9pp/)

Comment: Your best bet will be inline styles

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of your code.!

Comment: weBer, https://jsfiddle.net/31e2y9pp/